# change the page title of user page

Tags: users, 7

the html title of the user pages are the user id and the website name. Is there a way to instead change the user id to the user name?

ie.

[user id] | website name >>> [user: name] | website name

Answer (score 2):

For a no-code solution try the [page title](http://drupal.org/project/page_title) module, which allows you to override page titles all over the site, with the use of tokens to improve flexibility.